Multiple GTM variables that can be user_id - how to send the correct one to GA4?
The website I am managing exposes the user's unique ID in a number of different places depending upon the journey they take. The user ID may be retrieved from the data layer a referring URL parameter or a page parameter.
In GTM I am retrieving the user ID and storing in 5 different variables, only 1 of which will have the actual ID - the others will be NULL values.
If I want to send the actual user ID to GA4 using the user_id event parameter how can I select the value that may be in 1 of 5 variables without having the correct value overwritten by NULLs?
I can imagine a JS script might do it, but I don't know where that would live and be executed.

Fortunately the blank variables weren't 'NULL' but 'undefined'. This meant I could use the GTM 'Lookup Table' variable and test for an undefined value using the 'Undefined' GTM variable.
If the input variable value was 'undefined' then the table would use another defined variable, if not undefined then you can set the default value to the same as the 'input' or another variable depending on the logic needed. You can cascade these as per the suggestion from @Eike Pierstorff .

You can create a custom Javascript variable in GTM - that takes the form of an anonymous function that has to return a value, and there you can just run a few if/else clauses.
Custom Javascript variables are run with eval and are a bit slow and might not work under all content security policies, but unless you specifically set a CSP it will probably not matter.
A more "native" way to GTM would be default values. In a variable, you can use another variable as default value if a value is undefined (not sure if it works with null values).
So you would have a datalayer variable "user_id_from_dl". Then you set the default value to a url variable "user_id_from_url". Then you set that default value to "user_id_from_global_var" or whatever your source is.
Then you can just use the user_id_from_dl variable, and if the value is undefined it will default to the next thing, cascading through all the defaults until it finally finds a value of comes back undefined.
Drawback is that this is not necessarily the most transparent solution.

Thanks - just started to test and realised there are no default value settings for HTTP and URL variable types. Did you mean to have dummy values for the DL vars so you can use the default values? Then default from one DL var to the other?

Oh good call. You should still be able to use the "convert undefined" in the "format value" advanced options, since that supports variables as well. But in the interest of readibility a custom js might not be such a bad idea after all.

Your solution did trigger a thought and solution I'll post here.
